# directory lookup for the file failed with the operating system error 5(access is denied.)

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I had SQL Server 2008 R2. I uninstalled it and installed SQL Server 2012 - now I can't attach database or back up database because I have error:

directory lookup for the file failed with the operating system error 5(access is denied.)

What should I do? :(

Comment: Does the user you installed SQL with have permissions to the folders you are trying to read / write from? Get into the services section of manage my computer and see what the current running user is on the SQL server and then check your disk permissions for that user.

Comment: I have the same user: michael-PC like in SQL Server 2008 R2 (where I haven't permission problems).

Comment: look at the .mdf and .ldf file permission on the folder. michael-PC  might not have full control permission (on folder or files)

Comment: The account the sql server service is running as needs permission for the folder and files. That's not (or well shouldn't be) you. Check teh account information on the service. Or move the files to where master.mdb is and make sure the permissions are that same as they on that file.

Comment: how can I check teh account information on the service?

Answer (score 2):

Do check your directory path at which Backup and Restore taking place. (some folder might be deleted). 
Also solution would be you can backup **using scripts** and there you could avoid this error by mentioning the path to backup or restore database.

Refer to 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlkjmanageability/thread/1d044ccd-9c16-4a60-819d-cf7f9125384c

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2012 runs with your user account , so if you don't have read and right access, you will get this error so give your account administrator rights or proper rights needed to perform your task.